# Which tests for which $n$ (classification)

Tags: classification, inference, small-sample

in the feedback model I use, I have 3 types of feedback that can be naturally given to a student during a lab. The type of feedback (should) influence the cognitive load (CL) of the student. The CL is measure with a EEG in this case and we use an index to determine if the CL is high or low (referring to resting-stage, mean and overload).
I have the baseline data (raw measure) and the $Z$ score to compare the students. So is feedback $a$ determine a higher CL than feedback $b$ ?
Or, is feedback $a$ differs in CL if measure at 3 specific time during cursus ?

My independent variable is nominal (3 types) and my dependent is either an interval ($Z$) or a result.

I want to distinguish my types ($a$, $b$ or $c$) by its influence on the dependent.

But… I have $n=10$ that I can sample at 3 different times.
(Is there a difference between my samples in time?)

Or I have $n=30$ that I sample just once.
(Is there a difference between my types depending on the results?)

Or I have $n=30$, but taken from the same sample, but students with 3 different levels of expertise (so, it is like 10, 10, 10 ?).
(Both scenarios, but statistically weak for parametric analysis I think)

Which statistical tests should I process for each scenario---Student, ANOVA, Wilcoxon?
Thank you

Comment: A  couple of us have fixed multiple spelling errors for readability. As you are typing, watch for red underlines which often indicate incorrect spelling (perhaps more reliably for plain English than for technical terminology). // As for the substance of your question, you would likely get more helpful answers by giving a couple of specific examples.

Comment: I Bruce, thanks for the update (and sorry for the spelling errors, English is not my first language…). I have 3 types of feedback that can be naturally given to a student during a lab. The type of feedback (should, we think) influence the cognitive load (CL) of the student. The CL is measure with a EEG in this case and we use an index to determine if the CL is high or low. I have the baseline data (raw ratio) and the Z score to compare the students. So is feedback S determine a higher CL than feedback B ? Or, is feedback A differs in CL if measure at 3 specific time during the cursus ?

Comment: Oh and Wich tests wi(t)ch was just some humour to get attention...

Comment: Even native English speakers struggle with correct spelling. That's what in-line spell-checkers are for. English spelling will probably never be regularized. Many spelling quirks emulate local accents, so there are always objections to spelling reform. For me, speaking a brand of midwestern US English, the long 'o' sounds in _note, vote, wrote_ are not distinguishable from the ones in _goat, moat, boat,_ but in much of the UK the differences are quite clear. And then there are Australians and South Africans, etc.